# SQL to update/insert/union

Tags: sql, insert

I have two tables, table1 and table2. I want table1 to be updated based on transactions on table 2.
the data have no DB shape, I can add ids for table1 persons and table2 transactions.
I want to get updated table1. it is possible but I couldn't handle the complications.

[image]

Comment: use Triggers for updating table

Comment: the procedure is not an on going event to use triggers, the merge happen only once and it's done.

Comment: Explain question more

Comment: table 1 contains some people with some assets, for example, person A holds 50 units of asset, B holds 60 units and ... in Table2, transactions happen, for example, person A buys 20 units of assets from person B (first row), then in table 1, person A assets increase by 20 (70) and person B assets decrease by 20 (40). other transactions happen as table 2 and will result in "updated table 1"

Answer (score 3):

Try this. Example of using MERGE operator in MS SQL and PostgreSql

```
create table table1 (PersonCurrentAsset varchar(20),Quantity float);
insert into table1 values
('A',50),('B',60),('C',70);
create table table2(Quantity float,Seller varchar(20),Buyer varchar(20));
insert into table2 values
 (20,'B','A')
,(70,'C','D')
,(30,'A','E')
,(70,'D','B')
;

with trans as(
select Asset,sum(qty) as qty 
from(
  select Seller as Asset, -Quantity as qty from table2
  union all
  select Buyer as Asset, Quantity as qty from table2
  ) t
group by Asset
)
merge table1 as trg
using trans on asset=PersonCurrentAsset
when matched and (quantity+qty)=0 then
  delete
when matched then
  update set quantity=quantity+qty
when not matched and qty>0 then
  insert values(Asset,qty)
;
```

Without CTE

```
merge table1 as trg
using (select Asset,sum(qty) as qty 
   from(
        select Seller as Asset, -Quantity as qty from table2
        union all
        select Buyer as Asset, Quantity as qty from table2
      ) t
  group by Asset
) trans on asset=PersonCurrentAsset
when matched and (quantity+qty)=0 then
  delete
when matched then
  update set quantity=quantity+qty
when not matched and qty>0 then
  insert values(Asset,qty)
;
```

Postgresql syntax

```
merge into table1 as trg
using (select Asset,sum(qty) as qty 
   from(
        select Seller as Asset, -Quantity as qty from table2
        union all
        select Buyer as Asset, Quantity as qty from table2
      ) t
  group by Asset
) trans on asset=PersonCurrentAsset
when matched and (quantity+qty)=0 then
  delete
when matched then
  update set quantity=quantity+qty
when not matched and qty>0 then
  insert values(Asset,qty)
;
```

In MySQL - 2 operators.
`PersonCurrentAsset varchar(20)  primary key` is necessary.

```
create table table1 (PersonCurrentAsset varchar(20)  primary key ,Quantity float);
insert into table1 values
('A',50),('B',60),('C',70);
create table table2(Quantity float,Seller varchar(20),Buyer varchar(20));
insert into table2 values
 (20,'B','A')
,(70,'C','D')
,(30,'A','E')
,(70,'D','B')
;


insert into table1 
select * from (
select Asset,sum(qty) as qty 
   from(
        select Seller as Asset, -Quantity as qty from table2
        union all
        select Buyer as Asset, Quantity as qty from table2
      ) t
  group by Asset
)trans
on duplicate key  
  update  quantity=quantity+qty
;
delete from table1 where Quantity=0;
```

Updated: Similar `merge` works in Oracle. Example by @Ponder Stibbons

```
create table table2 (quantity, seller, buyer) as (
  select 20, 'B', 'A' from dual union all
  select 70, 'C', 'D' from dual union all
  select 30, 'A', 'E' from dual union all
  select 70, 'D', 'B' from dual );
create table table1(quantity, personcurrentasset) as (
  select 50, 'A' from dual union all
  select 60, 'B' from dual union all
  select 70, 'C' from dual );
merge into table1 using (
  select person, sum(qty) as qty from (
    select seller as person, -quantity as qty from table2 union all
    select buyer, quantity as qty from table2) 
  group by person) src
on (table1.personcurrentasset = src.person)
when matched then update set quantity = quantity + qty delete where quantity = 0
when not matched then 
  insert (quantity, personcurrentasset) values (qty, person) where qty <> 0
```

Comment: Than you, it does have some errors, also can you please rewrite it without CTE?

Comment: Query example without CTE added. What kind errors? What RDBMS you are using?

Comment: Similar `merge` works in Oracle too, with minor changes: [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/gItP2ZQj).

Comment: @Ponder Stibbons,
If you don't mind, I'll include your version for Oracle database to my answer, for completeness ?

Comment: OK, please include.